# Change the terminal prompt

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, root

This can be really trivial,but it helps in ways of making it more comfortable while coding and sending commands to terminal.

My terminal source/bash/root name(my apologies, I dunno which is the right word), reads as follows :

```
itachi@itachi-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Can you please tell me how Can I shorten this or change it? The second part after '@' is too long. Is there anyway to change this.? Thanks in advance..

Comment: You edit / set your prompt in ~/.bashrc, there are several options. See the answer above as well as http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html You could also shorten your hostname.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the following command in a terminal to open `~/.bashrc` file:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

When `.bashrc` opens, locate and uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes` (remove the hash, so it no longer looks like: `#force_color_prompt=yes`) and change the value of `PS1` in something like:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@<anything-you-want>\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

More about: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Answer (score 1):

The second part after the @ is the name of your computer. Change it!
Change it in 2 places:
`sudo gedit /etc/filename`
Replace 'filename' first by 'hosts' and then by 'hostname'
then find "itachi-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC" and change it to a desired name. Make sure that the name you choose is without spaces.
Save the file.

Restart the computer and you are done! Samjha?

Comment: Thanks for additional info :). It worked with the previous answer too. This is good info to know :).